# CoffeeScript and erb : require variable file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, erb, asset-pipeline, require

In my rails 3.1 App, I have 3 different javascript files for my html table. Let say, table1.js.coffee, table2 and table3.

In my application.js file, I have :

```
// = require table
```

And in my table.js.coffee.erb, I wish to do something like that :

```
// = require <%= 'table2' %>
// or (more useful)
// = require <%= Settings.js_table %>
```

Like this, I will be able to change my table's behavior from an extern config file. For the moment, it's not working. And I was wondering if it's possible ?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using erb variable in rails asset pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494181/using-erb-variable-in-rails-asset-pipeline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work.

Files in the pipeline are compiled on the first request, based on their contents (and any resolved erb) at that time.

If you reference something inside a pipeline file it will not update if that is changed elsewhere.

Edit in response to comment:

Sorry, I should have been clearer. The general case of this won't work.

In the case of using it with require, the `require` statement is a Sprockets specific directive. It is processed by Sprockets before the erb handler gets it.

The directive requires one argument - a string. In this case you have passed 3 arguments to the require directive: an opening erb tag, a quoted string, and a closing erb tag.

Thats why you get a 3 for 1 argument error.

The best (and possibly) only way to include files dynamically at run time is from your view layer.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But even the `= require <%= 'table2' %>` doesn't work. I catch this error : `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1)`